# I'd like to know how to create map or floor plan with wpf

Tags: .net, wpf

I'd like to know how to create map or floor plan with wpf.

For example to create an interactive plan floor of a house. Where each plant would be accessible as an object.

[image]

Is there any way other than by manually drawing Expression Blend?

Comment: there are LOTS of ways.  you're going to need to add a lot more information about what you've tried and what you're doing and why, or you risk getting this closed as being to vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF includes good support for [basic drawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx).  You could use this to draw the filled rectangles and text, as needed, on a Canvas.

Comment: New Link Location:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms747393(v=vs.100).aspx